# mysql - sumar los ultimos registros de un campo de una tabla

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Esta es la bd de datos con su relacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es sumar el ultimo registro de la tabla abonos el campo saldo de cada cuenta.

Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
select MONTHNAME(fecha) as mes,sum(saldo_abono) as saldo, sum(cantidad) as tabono
   from abonos
     GROUP by mes
```

y obtengo lo siguiente;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es que me esta sumando todos los saldos que se han realizado en un mes de un registro y solo quiero que coja el ultimo registro del saldo de esa cuenta y lo sume con los otros ultimos registro del saldo de las otras cuentas.

para ser mas especifico dejo esta captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver pepita perez tiene varios registros de abono y el campo saldo va diminuyendo. En un mes dio dos abonos y quiero que solo en ese mes escoja el ultimo registro que quedo en el saldo y lo sume con otros registros de los demas clientes.

Espero que me entiendan, cuaquier duda me comentan.

Comment: Solo quieres que coja el último registro de saldos, y que pasa con el campo que llamas tabono, también tiene que ser el último?

Comment: @Japv El de abono no, ese si tengo que sumarlos todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo logre solucionar con esta consulta:

```
select MONTHNAME(fecha) as mes, SUM(saldo_abono) as saldo
  FROM abonos abo
   WHERE idabono = (SELECT max(ab.idabono) FROM abonos ab
   WHERE cuenta_id = abo.cuenta_id AND MONTHNAME(fecha) = MONTHNAME(abo.fecha))
     GROUP BY mes;
```

Answer (score 1):

En este caso para evitar duplicidad, necesito agrupar las dos consultas, y yo las genero en subconsultas.

La primera es donde obtengo las sumas de los abonos, agrupadas por `cuenta_id` y `mes`.

La segunda obtengo la ultima fecha de la tabla cuentas, agrupada por `idcuenta` y `mes`.

En mi consulta final hago un join entre las dos por idcuenta y mes, además realizo un join de nuevo con la tabla cuentas para obtener el saldo de la ultima fecha que genere en mi subconsulta por cada idcuenta, y realizo las sumas y agrupado.

```sql
SELECT SUM(a.cantidad) as tabono, a.mes, SUM(c.saldo) tsaldo
FROM (
    SELECT  cuenta_id, SUM(a.cantidad) cantidad, MONTHNAME(a.fecha) as mes 
    FROM abonos a
    GROUP BY cuenta_id, MONTHNAME(a.fecha)
  ) a
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  idcuenta, MONTHNAME(c.fecha) as mes, MAX(c.fecha) fecha
    FROM cuentas c
    GROUP BY idcuenta, MONTHNAME(c.fecha)
  )temp ON a.cuenta_id = temp.idcuenta AND a.mes=temp.mes
  INNER JOIN cuentas c ON a.cuenta_id = c.idcuenta AND temp.idcuenta = c.idcuenta AND MONTHNAME(c.fecha)=temp.mes and temp.fecha = c.fecha
GROUP BY mes;
```

Te agrego un ejemplo que realice, para validar [Ejemplo SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b63b7/15)

Comment: Si necesito la suma del saldo pero solo del ultimo registro del saldo de cada cuenta.

Comment: Te actualice mi respuesta, básicamente agregue la suma de saldos de cuentas, en la consulta y metí la suma de abonos en otra subconsulta, para evitar que se dupliquen los saldos si tiene mas de un abono en el mes.

Comment: Estoy ejecutando a consulta pero veo que la suma de las cantidads no me la esta haciendo, lo de la suma de los saldos de los ultimos registros si, lo raro es que hago la consulta y no me devuelve el registro del mes de noviembre.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df3acaf/1, Esta es la nueva consulta que genere y si me suma los saldos

Comment: Me sigue sin funcionar, no entiendo esta parte de tu codigo:  `SELECT  cuenta_id, SUM(a.cantidad) cantidad ` haces doble select de esta suma y a esta le coloca cantidad porque?

Comment: por que agrupo primero por mes una suma de los abonos y te regresara 1 registro por id de cuenta, por mes, con la suma de los abonos, si no agrupas antes los abonos, te sumara un saldo final por cada registro de abono que tengas y te hará la suma de todos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115595/discussion-between-juanzu-and-eduardo-jaramillo-licea).

Answer (score -1):

si tienes un identificador numerico autoincrementeal puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
select sum(saldo_abono ) from (select MAX(id),cuenta_id, saldo_abono from abonos group by cuenta_id)
```

Puede que tenga errores pero la idea es esa.
la consulta interna es para seleccionar el ultimo abono de cada cuenta y el de afuera es para sumar el saldo de esa consulta

Comment: he intentado organizar el codigo pero igual no me corre, no soy muy bueno en mysql